# How to separate Li items when selecting multiple options in a variable product?

Tags: javascript, html, woocommerce

I am creating a feature on a Woocommerce variable product page where a user can select an option and that option gets added to a summary of items selected. I have multiple variations on the page so I have tried to get the innerHTML of every selected target and tried to add it to the UL by dynamically creating an li and adding to it. But at the moment only one li gets created and it adds all the options selected to it. Is there a way to separate each variation into multiple li's so that it adds the selected option to its own individual li? This is what I have so far.[example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCrfZ.jpg). It would be greatly appreciated if I am pointed in the right direction. Thanks a lot :)

```
var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.rtwpvs-terms-wrapper');
        var summary = document.querySelector('.selection-summary');
        var list = document.querySelector('.selected-items');
        var li = document.createElement("li");

        wrappers[0].classList.remove('opacity');

        let increment = 0;

        wrappers.forEach((item, sel) => {
            item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                summary.style.display = 'block';

                // Create li items and assign on click innerhtml
                li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(e.target.innerHTML));
                list.appendChild(li);

                increment++;
                for(var i = 0; i < wrappers.length; i++) {
                    wrappers[increment].classList.remove('opacity');
                }
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're appending to the same `li` (which you created at the top level) at every iteration of your loop. You should be creating a new `<li>` for each item, and append said `<li>` to your list, like so:

```
    // Create li items and assign on click innerhtml
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
    list.appendChild(li);
```

You don't need the `var li = document.createElement("li");` at the top level anymore.